# VST plugin create multiple windows

Tags: vst

Is it possible to create multiple windows in VST? 
For example, I have a created a knob. As I move the knob, a different window should be created for each movement.

Edit1: Sorry for not being clean enough. I have a parent window and have a button on it. Once I click on the button it should display a new window. How to do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The host supplies one parent window (frame). What you do with that is your choice. I would suggest creating one child window and showing 'tabs' in that. Note that changes in (child) window size may be tricky to get working on different host applications. [2c]

Comment: +1 for obiwanjacobi's comment.

Comment: @obiwanjacobi: can you please explain how to create a child window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding, using windows programming a we need to create our own GUI instead of using VSTGUI Library. Doing so we can create sub windows is my understanding. I have not tried this though.